# What is the best way to increase digital I/O lines on Pi?

Tags: gpio, pwm, analog-to-digital

In one of my projects I need six [PWM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) outputs, 12 digital I/O and around six analog inputs to be controlled by a Raspberry Pi. What are some of the best options available to increase the I/O capability of the Raspberry Pi?

For PWM, I am thinking of getting [SPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus)-based 12 to 16 channel PWM controllers from [Adafruit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adafruit). For other requirements, are there any easy-to-use products available?

Currently, the only option that comes to my mind is to wire various digital decoders, ADCs, etc. to the Raspberry Pi and control them using available I/O lines. I am looking for more robust and easy solution like [I²C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) or SPI-interface-based controllers.

Comment: there are plenty of I2C enabled ADC converters or digital input chips everywhere, and this is totally unrelated to Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I am looking for some examples which are known to work with raspberry pi.

Comment: any 100khz i2c should work, just don't buy 400khz "hi-speed" chips, these are more expensive and, in this particular case, the speed gain would not be worth time spent debugging.

Comment: I think your idea of the PWM controller from Adafruit is a good one. For the A2D, take a look at the Nwazet Key Lime Pi. http://nwazet.com/pi-keylime

Comment: key lime pi looks great. I wish they added IO expander, PWM and ADC all in one package.

Comment: The MCP23017 and the MCP23008 are very fine chips. Very easy to use and rugged. I fail to understand why one person says to avoid chips that have high speed capabilities. I have used dozens of I2c high speed devices on the RPI without issue,

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it can be a good idea to use a recommended chip (I²C, SPI, GPIO expander) from the wiringPi library because it's simpler to code specific software based on this library...
And you have a complete example (wiring, code) adapted to the Raspberry Pi.

Examples:

- [Extender GPIO example](http://wiringpi.com/extensions/shift-register-74x595/)
- [Analogic extender](http://wiringpi.com/extensions/i2c-pcf8591/)

Answer (score 1):

**AtoD DtoA**

[Board for PI](http://www.pridopia.co.uk/pi-2803-ad-da-1wire.html) This board has DtoA/AtoD, I2C and comes with scripts downloadable to get you started.

**PWM Board for 16 / 32 Channels**

[This board](http://www.pridopia.co.uk/pi-9685-23017-lp.html) has PWM and has SPI interface for 16 more Digital Pins.